# why does my glass look so strange especially when smooth shaded

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, glass

Here's what it looks like flat shaded, in cycles, with the settings. i only upped transmission to 1 and roughness down:

[image]

Here's what it looks like smooth shaded in cycles:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe your normals are flipped.  Check this box.

[image]

If your glass looks like this -

[image]

Enter *Edit Mode*, select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and select *Recalculate Outside*.

Your glass should look a bit better, but it looks to me like you should consider adding some supporting geometry on the top and bottom.

[image]